# How to "refresh" $(OutDir)

Tags: visual-studio-2012, properties

I changed "Output directory" but my `$(OutDir)` macro still has old value. How do update it?

Also let me add that the same `$(OutDir)` gives different (correct) path in other projects in the same solution (Output Directory everywhere is set to the same value)...

Comment: Your assumption that it needs to be "refreshed" is not correct.  You'll need to look for another reason.

Comment: Well, I know I can't manually update it, my question is - how the hell do I make it work?...